# Can you visit other people's towns between a 3DS and a 2DS?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Can you visit other people's towns between a 3DS and a 2DS on Animal Crossing New Leaf

My friends have it on the 3DS and use it to visit each other, but I was going to get the 2DS and was wondering if I could still visit them

Comment: I don't see why not; a 2ds is just a 3Ds without the 3d and close-able lid.

Comment: Of course you can, the game is still the same, it doesn't matter on which console.

Comment: I just asked because on GTAV you can't connect a PS4 to like an Xbox one so I thought it was like that

Answer (score 2):

For all 3DS games, and games in the 3DS family: The system you play it on may enable/disable individual options but you can generally play between a 2DS, 3DS, and New 3DS.

So Animal Crossing **will work on all three systems** and will allow for one system to visit another. Some other games (Xenoblade for example) will only work on the New 3DS. In a case like this, there's no option to play with the other two systems. Generally speaking, *if a game works on 2DS, it will be compatible for any of the 3DS family of systems.*